# Binarize poor quality image

Tags: c#, image, emgucv, threshold, adaptive-threshold

**UPDATED QUESTION:**

Is it possible to binarize this image? I have a list of image, exactly the same with this picture.

I want the image to have black and white value only.

**UPDATE:**

I tried to binarize and remove noises from my images, but this is what I get. 
[image]

```
for (int x = 0; x < ExtractedBoxes.Count(); x++)
{
    FiltersSequence seq = new FiltersSequence();
    seq.Add(new Grayscale(0.2125, 0.7154, 0.0721));  //First add  GrayScaling filter
    seq.Add(new SISThreshold()); //Then add binarization(thresholding) filter
    ExtractedBoxes[x] = seq.Apply(ExtractedBoxes[x]); // Apply filters on source image
}
```

I tried to use that because it's the easiest way I found, but I think not efficient enough. It's from Aforge.net library. I used SISThreshold, because I can't get otsu threshold working, and Otsu is what I'm familiar the most.

Hoping you could give me better approach or other ways to clean them up. Thanks!

Comment: You already tagged your question with the keywords you should search. What do you want from us? Write it for you?

Comment: It is of course possible, but it looks like the threshold changes substantially per image.

Comment: @Magus I'd imagine that you'd want to go with a deviation from average  brightness or something like that, to cope with the varying intensity.

Comment: So I need something like threshold value that adapts? or that changes depending on the quality of the image?

Comment: You probably need a lot of things. In this context, that includes code, if you want an answer to your question. Otherwise we're just going to give vague suggestions.

Comment: I'll post one, please wait

Comment: @Magus I have updated my code. Please take a look

Comment: Looks to me like you need a better threshold, which may be rather difficult. You clearly need one closer to black, and it will need to change depending on the image. Otherwise, cases like 2 and 15, where the colors are very dark will have far more black than others. Jeff had a good suggestion about adaptive brightness. My suggestion would be to sample the colors in an image and select the last one before the jump, since your writing is always substantially darker than the background. You just need to figure out where that jump is.

Comment: @Magus-What do you mean by sample the colors and select the last one before the jump?